# Access Listbox second item doesn't show

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, listbox

I have listbox that should show 2 items: Yes, No. It's bound to a bit field in SQLServer. The listbox has 2 columns and the first one stores the 0 or 1 that is bound. Here are the properties that I change:

Design Time:

Column Count:2

Column Widths: 0" ;1"

Control Source: TheBitField

Row Source Type: Value List

Bound Column: 1

Limit To List: Yes

Allow Value List Edits: No

Inherit Value List: No

Run Time:

cboYesNoChoice.RowSource = ""

cboYesNoChoice.RowSource = "0,'no';1,'yes'"

when running the listbox shows both choices correctly when dropped down. Problem is that when I click 'Yes' the listbox shows empty. Selecting 'No' shows correctly in the listbox. What's the problem with showing the second list item?

Comment: Is TheBitField a yes/no type? Yes/No type stores 0 for false and -1 for true.

Comment: Yes, it is linked to SQL Server table's field of type bit.

Comment: I assumed backend of Access. Missed the reference to SQL in question. Should include SQLServer tag. Sorry, no idea why Access has issue. But maybe this will help http://msgroups.net/access.formscoding/datatype-bit-problem-with-access-front-end/76194

Comment: Try changing this `cboYesNoChoice.RowSource = "0,'no';1,'yes'"` to `cboYesNoChoice.RowSource = "0,'no';-1,'yes'"`.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing separators, so try:

```
cboYesNoChoice.RowSource = "0;'no';1;'yes'"
```

or:

```
cboYesNoChoice.RowSource = "0;no;1;yes"
```

Or replace semicolon with comma if semicolon is not your list separator.